# Reverse a for loop of an array

Tags: swift, xcode, coordinates, mapkit

I'm try to create a func that should calculate the coordinate at 90deg and 270deg from each of the given coordinate..

and save it in an array of arrayLocationOffset

```
var arrayLocations : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] =
    [
     CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.15055543976834, longitude: 11.656891939801518 ),
     CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.154446871287924, longitude: 11.66058789179949),
    ]
// simplify only 2 coordinate
```

I use this for loop in order to perform the action:

```
 func createCoordinatePoly() {
        let polypoint = arrayLocations.count
     
        for i in 0..<polypoint {
          
            let coord = arrayLocations[i]
            
            // calc LH
            
            let lhCoord = coord270(coord: coord)
            
            arrayLocationOffset.append(lhCoord)
            
        }
        
        for i in 0..<polypoint { // shuld revers this for loop and get first the last index
            
            let coord = arrayLocations[i]
            
            // calc LH
            
            let RhCoord = coord90(coord: coord)
            
            arrayLocationOffset.append(RhCoord)
            
        }
        
        debugPrint("aggiunto array poly \(arrayLocationOffset.count)")
        
    }
```

The arrayLocationOffset must have a specific sequence otherwise I can't properly draw a polygon in the Mapkit.
In order get the specific order on the second forLoop (where I calculate RHside) I should start to calculate from last array index back to the first...

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies you can reverse an array just with `reversed()`.

Your code is rather *objective-c-ish*. A better way to enumerate the array is fast enumeration because you actually don't need the index.

```
for coord in arrayLocations { ...
```

and

```
for coord in arrayLocations.reversed() { ...
```

---

However there is a still *swiftier* way `map`ping the arrays

```
func createCoordinatePoly() {
    arrayLocationOffset.append(contentsOf: arrayLocations.map{coord270(coord: $0)})
    arrayLocationOffset.append(contentsOf: arrayLocations.reversed().map{coord90(coord: $0)})    
    debugPrint("aggiunto array poly \(arrayLocationOffset.count)")        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

solved:

```
var reversIndex = polypoint-1
        for _ in 0..<polypoint {
            
            let coord = arrayLocations[reversIndex]
            
            // calc LH
            
            let RhCoord = coord90(coord: coord)
            
            arrayLocationOffset.append(RhCoord)
            reversIndex -= 1
        }
```

I use a reverse index to start from the end...

Comment: Why not just `for i in (0..<polypoint).reversed()`?